# Number of elements of order $p$ is a multiple of $p-1$ (finite group).

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

This is a question in Pinter's *A Book of Abstract Algebra*.

> Let $S=\{g\in G\mid \operatorname{ord}(g)=p\}$. Prove the order of $S$ is a multiple of $p-1$.

In his solution Pinter says $a \in S$ implies that $a$ generates a subgroup with $p-1$ elements. Shouldn't there be $p$ elements $\{1,a^1,\dots,a^{p-1}\}$? Or is it typical to only count the non-trivial elements in a subgroup?

Comment: Hint: What is the order of 1?

Comment: The unit element has order $1$.

Comment: I suppose that $G$ is a group and $p$ is a prime number. You should include such information into your question.

Comment: You're right in that $a$ will generate a subgroup of order $p$. I think the point is that the subgroup will have $p - 1$ elements of order $p$, and then the identity. So the elements of order $p$ come in $(p - 1)$-sized bunches.

Comment: One way of looking at this is that $(\mathbf Z/p\mathbf Z)^*$ acts on $S$ by $n.x = x^n$, and the orbits of this action (which partition $S$) all have size $p - 1$, since the stabilizers are all trivial.

Answer (score 5):

No, you are right, every element $a \in S$ generates a subgroup with $p$ elements. However, only $p-1$ of those will lie in the set $S$, which I guess is what Pinter means.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that the sentence is to be read "every element in $S$ generates a subgroup that has $p-1$ elements in $S$".

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, an element of order $n$ generates a subgroup with $n$ elements. Perhaps Pinter means that the subgroup generated by an element of order $p$ contains $p-1$ elements of order $p$ (namely, the nontrivial ones).